# The relationship of one model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a problem with Laravel relationships.

I need to make relationship based on this table:

[image: table]

`issuer` and `friend` need to be united. Relationship will return all rows where user id in `issuer` or in `friend`. At the moment code looks like this:

```php
return DB::table('contacts')->select()->where('friend', $this->id)->orWhere('issuer', $this->id)->where('status', 'approved');
```

Previously I used that method, but there are no relationship, 'cause `attach()` is undefined.

```php
    private function contactsIssued() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'contacts','issuer', 'friend');
    }

    private function contactsFriended() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'contacts','friend', 'issuer');
    }

    public function contacts() {
        return $this->contactsIssued()->union($this->contactsFriended()->toBase());
    }
```

So, I need to make one relationship that has two foreign columns.

*Sorry, my English can be broken, 'cause it's not my native language.*

Comment: So what's the exact problem your having? What do you want to achieve and where do you fail?

Comment: So, I need ONE relationship for two equal columns, but I don’t know how to do it

Comment: @wschopohl Added main question, sorry

Comment: You are missing `get()`,  `return DB::table('contacts')->select()->where('friend', $this->id)->orWhere('issuer', $this->id)->where('status', 'approved')->get();`

Comment: @STA Main question isn't about that

Comment: In your first approach you are using query builder not the eloquent relationship. Try to do something like `where(function($q) { $q->where('friend', $this->id); $q->orWhere('issuer', $this->id);})->...`

Comment: @FelippeDuarte Can I make my own custom relationship, that have ability to control attach/detach functions?

Comment: I dunno, but you can always encapsulate it, like `$model->attachContacts($data)` and inside your model you can implement `function attachContacts($data) { $this->issues->attach(); ... $this->friends->attach()`}

Comment: @FelippeDuarte Okay, I try to use additional methods to attach/detach, but even so I want relationship

Comment: Hm.. Why my question has a lot of downvotes?

Answer (score -1):

That's look like a `one to many` relationship but you are using `belongsToMany` which is `many to many` relationship and required a `pivot` table.

if you have `user` model that has many `contact` model then in your `contact` model you should use the `one to many` relationship by using `belongsTo`.

but if you have 3 table you didn't say that in you question then please edit you question and provide your models and the relations between them.

Comment: Emm.. Please, look at the table, it's clearly look like pivot table

Comment: I said if it's many to many please provide your db structure so i can help. but you just vote down .. sorry for tring to help you

Comment: I don't votedown your answer, 'cause I don't have reputation to votedown.

Comment: In StackOverflow there are no any way to find who down vote on your question